# jquery my else if part not working... what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a DOM manipulation using jQuery's `map` function. Using this I am trying to append an element to a form.

It works fine only one time; by that mean I am getting the result only in the `if`  portion, I can't get any value from the `else if` portion. What is wrong with my function, or is my approachwrong?

My data:

```
"fields":[
            {
               "id":"firstname",
               "label":"First Name",
               "name":"fname",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"email",
               "label":"Email",
               "name":"email",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"countries",
               "label":"Country",
               "name":"countries",
               "type":"select",
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"",
                     "text":"Select Country"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"in",
                     "text":"India",
                      "selected":"true"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"us",
                     "text":"United Stated"

                  },
                  {
                     "value":"uk",
                     "text":"United Kingdom"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"cn",
                     "text":"Canada"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"submit",
               "name":"submit",
               "type":"submit",
               "value":"Submit"
            }
         ]
```

My function:

```
    var processModules = function (mData) {
        $.map(mData, function (val,i) {
            $(val.container).append(
                $(val.type === 'content' || val.type === 'navigation' ?
                $('<div />',{
                    'class':val.attributes['class'],
                    id:val.attributes.id})
                .append(val.title ? $('<h2 />',{text:val.title}) : "")
                .append(val.subtitle ? $('<h3>',{text:val.subtitle}) : "")
                :
                val.type === 'form' ? $('<form />',{
                    id:val.attributes.id,
                    'class':val.attributes['class'],
                    action:val.action,
                    name:val.name
                })
                .append($('<legend />',{text:val.title}))
                .append(
                    $.map(val.fields, function (val,i) {
var element;
                        if(val.id) {
                            console.log(val.id); // getting values and appending elements
                        }
                        if (val.label) {
                            element = $('<label />',{text:val.label}); //  am not getting any value here..
                        }
                        if (val.type) {
                            element = $('<input />',{id:val.id}) // I am only getting value here..
                        }
                    } )
                )
                : ""));
        } )
    }
```

What is the issue? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The answers cover the if/else thing, but unrelated to that you should be using `$.each()` rather than `$.map()`. `$.each()` is for iterating over each element/property of an array/object, which is what you are doing. `$.map()` also iterates over the items, but it is intended to create a new array based on some processing that you do to the items in the old.

Answer (score 1):

`else if` only gets called if the previous if/else if statements weren't. For example:

```
if (true) {
    // This code gets run
}

else if (true) {
    // This code never will
}
```

With that in mind, change your if statements to be like the following:

```
if(val.id) {
    console.log(val.id);
}

if (val.label) {
    console.log(val.label);
}

if (val.type) {
    console.log(val.type);
}
```

Comment: i got your point. and i changed my code, but only the first part of if condition appending, rest not works...

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected, your would not get to the else part if the first if evaluates to true. Once `if(val.id)` returns true all the rest would be skipped

Comment: I changed to if condition, using this i am trying to append elements, but it not appending at all... i updated my code can you suggest me a good way?

Comment: try to put a console.log before the if call to see what values you are getting for `val.label` and `val.type` to see why it is not evaluating to `true`